# Typeorm query by target

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

I have one problem. so I have an immunization request table and it can have a vaccine or immunization. so I didn't want relationships like vaccineId and immunizationId. I created target = Vaccine or Immunization and targetId.

like this:

```
  /** ImmunizationRequest can have vaccine = targetType=Vaccine targetId= vaccine id. */
  @ManyToOne(() => Vaccine, { eager: true, nullable: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn()
  vaccine: Vaccine;

  /** ImmunizationRequest can have immunization = targetType=Immunization targetId= vaccine id. */
  @ManyToOne(() => Immunization, { eager: true, nullable: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn()
  immunization: Immunization;
```

now I want to get all immunization requests and if the type is Vaccine then get the vaccine object and if it is Immunization then I must get the immunization object (relationship ).

So this is my query code

```
  const query = this.repository
      .createQueryBuilder('immunizationRequest')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('immunizationRequest.visit', 'visit')
      .addSelect(
        `CASE
          WHEN immunizationRequest.target = 'Vaccine' THEN vaccine.id
          WHEN immunizationRequest.target = 'Immunization' THEN immunization.id
          ELSE NULL
        END AS targetId,
        CASE
          WHEN immunizationRequest.target = 'Vaccine' THEN 'Vaccine'
          WHEN immunizationRequest.target = 'Immunization' THEN 'Immunization'
          ELSE NULL
        END AS targetType`,
      )
      .leftJoin('vaccine', 'v', 'v.id = immunizationRequest.targetId AND immunizationRequest.target = :vaccineType', {
        vaccineType: ImmunizationRequestTarget.VACCINE,
      })
      .leftJoin(
        'immunization',
        'i',
        'i.id = immunizationRequest.targetId AND immunizationRequest.target = :immunizationType',
        { immunizationType: ImmunizationRequestTarget.IMMUNIZATION },
      )

    const results = await query.getRawMany();
```

and am getting this error

**operator does not exist: uuid = character varying**

I know that am doing something wrong. How to fix this query?